How can I add a resource to BackupPlan.fromBackupPlanId
I have 2 repositories, infra and app.
In infra, I have:
const backupPlan = new BackupPlan(this, 'backup-plan', {/*...*/});

new CfnOutput(this, `backupPlanOutput`, {
  value: backupPlan.backupPlanId,
  exportName:`backupPlan`,
});

In app, I have:
const myTable = new Table(this, 'my-table', { /* ... */ });

How do I add my table in app to the backup plan in infra? IBackupPlan does not have addSelection
const backupPlan = BackupPlan.fromBackupPlanId(this, 'backup-plan', Fn.importValue('backupPlan'));
// cant do anything with this?


Off-topic: SO is showing that you answered the question within less than a second from posting it - how'd you manage that?

created the question and ticked the "answer your own question" box. I ran into this issue, could not find any solution anywhere, stumbled across the solution reading through the api, decided it needed to be posted

TIL, didn't know about that feature. Make sure to accept the answer, though

Use BackupSelection:
const backupPlan = BackupPlan.fromBackupPlanId(this, 'backup-plan', Fn.importValue('backupPlan'));

new BackupSelection(this, `backup-selection`, {
  backupPlan,
  resources: [BackupResource.fromDynamoDbTable(myTable)],
});

